# CLI bash, wanting to restart service or service

Tags: mysql, unix, restart

I am unsure of the syntax I would need to use to do:

/etc/init.d/mysql restart or /etc/init.d/mysqld restart

This is for scripts so it can be easily ported onto Ubuntu (mysql) or CentOS (mysqld).

I'm just wanted a quick one liner (if possible). Or would I need to actually do a "find" for what is in /etc/init.d/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different systems seems to name the mysql service differently, either mysql or mysqld. So you could try and restart the ones that exist.

```
[ -f /etc/init.d/mysql ] && /sbin/service mysql restart
[ -f /etc/init.d/mysqld ] && /sbin/service mysqld restart
```

This will likely break when distros convert the mysql service to systemd, as the startup files are no longer in /etc/init.d/

Comment: Yeah this kind of works. For Ubuntu 12 just removed /sbin/

Would have thought there would be "do this, if not exists, do this" kind of command in one :)

Comment: Well, you could always put the 2 lines here on one line with a `||` between them, or just a `;`

Answer (score 0):

This should work on most linux distributions:

```
sudo service mysqld restart
```